# How to send a GET request to webservice from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html form of which has an onClick attribute on it's button, that then calls a javascript function:

```
function submitForm () {

    // Get Session ID
    var sessionId = document.getElementById("session-id").value;

    // Get Description
    var description = document.getElementById("description").value;

    // Call WebService ??   

}
```

At this stage I have to call a webservice at this URL:

```
localhost:8080/PatientRefund/WebService?urnId=93&batchDescription=My%20Description
```

Where you can replace '93' with 'sessionId' and 'My%20Description' with 'batchDescription'. Also the request should be a GET request.

Can anyone just point me in the right direction? I'm not looking for you to write the code for me... Thanks guys :)

Comment: You want AJAX. Really easy to do e.g. using jQuery's `$.ajax()` or even `$.get()` shortcut.

Comment: perfect that's all I wanted, just wanted to see how all the cool kids are doing it these days since I'm not a javascript dev.

Comment: You can use [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery ajax, your code will be like:

```
function submitForm () {
    var sessionId = document.getElementById("session-id").value;
    var description = document.getElementById("description").value;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/PatientRefund/WebService',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {urnId: sessionId, batchDescription: description}
    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        // do something with your response
    });
}
```

If you want the clients to download a file after submit, you should not use ajax request. You should create a form dynamically and submit it. Example code:

```
function submitForm() {
    var sessionId = document.getElementById("session-id").value;
    var description = document.getElementById("description").value;
    var newForm = jQuery('<form>', {
        'action': 'http://localhost:8080/PatientRefund/WebService',
        'method': 'GET',
        'target': '_top'
    }).append(jQuery('<input>', {
        'name': 'urnId',
        'value': sessionId,
        'type': 'hidden'
    })).append(jQuery('<input>', {
        'name': 'batchDescription',
        'value': description,
        'type': 'hidden'
    }));
    newForm.submit();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: the response that I get back is actually a file that's supposed to get downloaded to the client. With your code above the service gets hit successfully but the file doesn't download. How do I handle this in the javascript?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry if you want to download a file you should not use ajax. You should create a form and post it to the WebService endpoint.

Comment: You're good! Didn't work though, I got this error: "A form was submitted in the windows-1252 encoding which cannot encode all Unicode characters, so user input may get corrupted. To avoid this problem, the page should be changed so that the form is submitted in the UTF-8 encoding either by changing the encoding of the page itself to UTF-8 or by specifying accept-charset=utf-8 on the form element."

Comment: Okay so that took the error away but the web service isn't even getting hit anymore. But, you've answered my original question so you deserve your points. I'll try and figure it out. Thanks for your help :)